# In Sybase Show row values as column names and fill this rows with values of another column

Tags: sybase

I have a table like

```
    ID | TableID | FieldNames | Values
     1 |    1    | FirstName  | Value 1    
     2 |    1    | LastName   | Value 2    
     3 |    1    | City       | Value 3
     4 |    2    | FirstName  | Value 4    
     5 |    2    | LastName   | Value 5    
     6 |    2    | City       | Value 6
```

I need to show it in a grid like below

```
   TableID | FirstName | LastName | City
      1    |   Value1  |  Value2  | Value3
      2    |   Value4  |  Value5  | value6
```

I know the concept PIVOT will help to get this implemented in MS SQL. But I need to implement this in Sybase. Field names are not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do a 3-way self-join:

```
SELECT t1.Value as FirstName, t2.Value as LastName, t3.Value as City 
FROM t t1, t t2, t t3 
WHERE t1.ID + 1 = t2.ID 
AND t1.ID +2 = t3.ID
```

Comment: Thanks @RobV. Number of fields is not fixed. Fields could be 3 or 4 or 10 or more.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of various posts I have figured it out that I can do this using a dynamic case statement, like below.

```
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(800)
    DECLARE @fieldName VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @LoopCounter INT, @MaxCount INT

    SET @query = 'select f.tableID,  '
    SET @fieldName = ''
    SET @LoopCounter = 1
    SET @MaxCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FieldNames) FROM dbo.Table1)

    WHILE (@LoopCounter <= @MaxCount)
    BEGIN

        SET @fieldName = (SELECT FieldNames FROM dbo.table1 WHERE ID= @LoopCounter)
        SET @query = @query + ' max(case when f.FieldNames = ''' + @fieldName +''' then f.[Values] end) AS ''' + @fieldName + ''''

        IF(@LoopCounter < @MaxCount)
        BEGIN
            SET @query = @query + ', '
        END

        SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1

    END

    SET @query = @query + ' FROM dbo.table1 f GROUP BY f.TableID'

    exec (@query)
```